# PubNub's heartbeat option doesn't work in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, pubnub, heartbeat

This simple code doesn't work in IE11.
I enter the code into console of http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/tutorial/pubnub.html

```
var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
 publish_key: 'demo',
 subscribe_key: 'demo'
});
pubnub.subscribe({
 channel: "test1",
 callback: function(m){console.log(m)},
 heartbeat: 6
});
```

I get these js errors

> SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'
>
> File: heartbeat, Line: 1, Column: 10
>
> Presence Heartbeat unable to reach Pubnub servers.undefined

Similar errors also happen in IE9 and IE10, but the behaviour is harder to reproduce, it seems to be related to pubnub's init ssl option.

Anyone experienced similar issues?
Really looks like a blocker for IE heartbeat usage.

Comment: PubNub is investigating this, please standby.

Comment: Thank you for submitting this issue.  As stated by Geremy, PubNub is investigating.

Comment: Checking back on the status here.

Comment: Also, IE has historically been super strict about semi-colons (throws exception) whereas other browsers are forgiving about the use of semi-colons.

The callback provided in the sample code lacks a semi-colon after console.log(m) but before the closing bracket. Adding a ";" there might fix it (didn't test this).

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in PubNub 3.6.5 release candidate.
Thanks for quick patch!